# Is Azure Table storage a column-oriented database like HBase

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I wonder to know how data is stored on disk in Azure Table? are they stored in a columnar format like HBase?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure Table is a form of Microsoft Azure Storage, a scalable cloud storage system. There are three layers within an Azure Storage stamp and Stream layer stores the bits on disk, and in charge of distributing and replicating the data across many servers to keep the data durable within a stamp. Please see “Stream Layer” section in the following paper (http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/11-calder-online.pdf) to understand how we manage data on the hardware.

Answer (score -1):

I can't say for sure, but I don't think so.  Azure Table Storage is a key-value store.  HDInsight is Azure's column-family storage, built on Hadoop, similar to HBase.

Comment: As a matter of fact column-oriented databases are key-value. HDInsight is microsoft cloud-base Hadoop service, not an storage!